How to get the project name when creating an item template in Visual Studio?
I want to create a project template in Visual Studio. The $rootnamespace$ and $safeitemname$ parameters work fine, but I also want to access the project name. I do it as follows, but instead of writing the project name, it remains as $projectname$ in the output.
UserControl.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="$rootnamespace$.$safeitemname$"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"   
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:$projectname$.ViewModels"  
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:$projectname$.Converters"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:$projectname$.Helpers"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"           
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:$rootnamespace$"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:$safeitemname$ViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
            
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

UserControl.xaml.cs
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    public partial class $safeitemname$ : UserControl
    {
        public $safeitemname$()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

UserControl.vstemplate
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name Package="{b3bae735-386c-4030-8329-ef48eeda4036}" ID="4664">SUserControl</Name>
    <Description Package="{b3bae735-386c-4030-8329-ef48eeda4036}" ID="4665"></Description>
    <Icon Package="{b3bae735-386c-4030-8329-ef48eeda4036}" ID="4594" />
    <TemplateID>Microsoft.CSharp.WPF.UserControl</TemplateID>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <AppliesTo>CSharp + (WPF | (!CPS + WindowsForms))</AppliesTo>
    <ShowByDefault>false</ShowByDefault>
    <SortOrder>98</SortOrder>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>3.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
    <NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>1</NumberOfParentCategoriesToRollUp>
    <DefaultName>SUserControl.xaml</DefaultName>
    <AppIdFilter>blend</AppIdFilter>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>System.Xaml</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>WindowsBase</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>PresentationCore</Assembly>
      </Reference>
      <Reference>
        <Assembly>PresentationFramework</Assembly>
      </Reference>
    </References>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" CustomTool="MSBuild:Compile">SUserControl1.xaml</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$safeitemname$.xaml.cs">SUserControl1.xaml.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>


According to the documentation, $projectname$ should work... this is weird.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, could this be related? So, I shared the example directly above, I wasn't sure what kind of error there was.

I wonder if it might be related to your use of references to really old VS/WPF versions (I think?), e.g. your <VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" and <RequiredFrameworkVersion>3.0 - what happens if you remove everything except the bare-minimum from your .vstemplate file?

I don't quite understand what you want me to remove in .vstemplate.

Try removing as many elements from <TemplateData> (and the Version="3.0.0" attribute from <VSTemplate>) as you can and see what happens.

I deleted many things and there was no change. The project is a .net core project, not a .net framework project. I suspected that this might have an impact. Do I need to add something special for .net core?

Unfortunately, it seems like it has nothing to do with it. I opened a .net framework project and the same problem persists.
